# I want to put the frequently used values in the cache? How and how can I know which all values are frequently used?

Tags: java

I want to put the frequently used values in the cache? How and how can I know which all values are frequently used?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do you want a map or a set for your values?
Second, do you want the most frequently used elements, or the recently used elements? Caches usually look at recently used.

You could implement something yourself, or use something like the [LRUMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api/org/apache/commons/collections/LRUMap.html) in Apache Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap those values with an object, that has a counter, that increases each time, the value is accessed. Then make a decision, based on values of that counters.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a [list of algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms) and their trade-offs. Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity maybe you can use **LinkedHashMap**, it can be created in **access order** mode. This way the last used (get/put) value will be first in map.values().